# I have a below array with some same keys with different values. How can I combine same keys values with that key in PHP? I am using WAMP, Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, key, key-value

I am getting these data from importing CSV file. In CSV file I have 1st column is Years and all other columns are Make. I am using csvreader library for parsing data from CSV file.

My CSVReader Library.

```
class CI_Csvreader {

    var $fields;        /** columns names retrieved after parsing */  
    var $separator = ',';    /** separator used to explode each line */  

    /** 
     * Parse a text containing CSV formatted data. 
     * 
     * @access    public 
     * @param    string 
     * @return    array 
     */  
    function parse_text($p_Text) {  
            $lines = explode("\n", $p_Text);  
            return $this->parse_lines($lines);  
    }  

    /** 
     * Parse a file containing CSV formatted data. 
     * 
     * @access    public 
     * @param    string 
     * @return    array 
     */  
    function parse_file($p_Filepath) {  
            $lines = file($p_Filepath);  
            return $this->parse_lines($lines);  
    }  
    /** 
     * Parse an array of text lines containing CSV formatted data. 
     * 
     * @access    public 
     * @param    array 
     * @return    array 
     */  
    function parse_lines($p_CSVLines) {  
            $content = FALSE;  
            foreach( $p_CSVLines as $line_num => $line ) {  
                    if( $line != '' ) { // skip empty lines  
                            $elements = explode($this->separator, $line);  

                            if( !is_array($content) ) { // the first line contains fields names  
                                    $this->fields = $elements;  
                                    $content = array();  
                            } else {  
                                    $item = array();  
                                    foreach( $this->fields as $id => $field ) {  
                                            if( isset($elements[$id]) ) {  
                                                    $item[$field] = $elements[$id];  
                                            }  
                                    }  
                                    $content[] = $item;  
                            }  
                    }  
            }  
            return $content;  
    }
```

My CSV file data =>

```
Years   Make    Make    Make
2001    Acura   Honda   Toyota
2002    Acura   Honda   
2003    Acura           Toyota
2004
```

In above file Years and Make data in Excel/CSV sheet can be changed later.

My output is an array.=>

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Years] => 2001
            [Make] => Acura
            [Make] => Honda
            [Make] => Toyota
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Years] => 2002
            [Make] => Acura
            [Make] => Honda
            [Make] => 
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Years] => 2003
            [Make] => Acura
            [Make] => 
            [Make] => Toyota
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [Years] => 2004
            [Make] => 
            [Make] => 
            [Make] => 
        )
)
```

I want my result array like this =>
I want to keep null values.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Years] => 2001
            [Make] => Array(
                              [0]=>Acura
                              [1]=>Honda
                              [2]=>Toyota
                           )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Years] => 2002
            [Make] => Array(
                              [0]=>Acura
                              [1]=>Honda
                              [2]=>
                           )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Years] => 2003
            [Make] => Array(
                              [0]=>Acura
                              [1]=>
                              [2]=>Toyota
                           )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [Years] => 2004
            [Make] => Array(
                              [0]=>
                              [1]=>
                              [2]=>
                           )
        )
)
```

Also please show me how to get result without null values.

If there any other way to get data from CSV file in my desired format that would be ok.

Can anyone please help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to parse your CSV file

```
function CSV_parse($string='', $has_header=true, $row_delimiter=PHP_EOL, $delimiter = "," , $enclosure = '"' , $escape = "\\" )
{
    $rows = array_filter(explode($row_delimiter, $string));
    $firstline = true;
    $data = array();

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        if($firstline && $has_header)
        {
            $firstline=false;
            continue;
        }

        $row = str_getcsv ($row, $delimiter, $enclosure , $escape);


        $dtrow=array('Years'=>$row[0], 'Makes'=>array());
        for($i=1;$i<count($row);$i++)
        {
            $make=trim($row[$i]);
            if($make=='')continue;
            $dtrow['Makes'][]=$make;
        }
        $data[] =$dtrow;

    }

    return $data;
}
```

you should pass as the first argument your CSV file content.
for the second argument you should pass false if your csv file has no header

EDIT ==>

You can modify just a few lines in this class to achieve desired results. Look at those line between PTK ==>  and <== PTK:

```
class CI_Csvreader {

    var $fields;        /** columns names retrieved after parsing */  
    var $separator = ',';    /** separator used to explode each line */  

    /** 
     * Parse a text containing CSV formatted data. 
     * 
     * @access    public 
     * @param    string 
     * @return    array 
     */  
    function parse_text($p_Text) {  
            $lines = explode("\n", $p_Text);  
            return $this->parse_lines($lines);  
    }  

    /** 
     * Parse a file containing CSV formatted data. 
     * 
     * @access    public 
     * @param    string 
     * @return    array 
     */  
function parse_file($p_Filepath) {  
        $lines = file($p_Filepath);  
        return $this->parse_lines($lines);  
}  
/** 
 * Parse an array of text lines containing CSV formatted data. 
 * 
 * @access    public 
 * @param    array 
 * @return    array 
 */  
function parse_lines($p_CSVLines) {  
        $content = FALSE;  
        foreach( $p_CSVLines as $line_num => $line ) {  
                if( $line != '' ) { // skip empty lines  
                        $elements = explode($this->separator, $line);  

                        if( !is_array($content) ) { // the first line contains fields names  
                                $this->fields = $elements;  
                                $content = array();  
                        } else {  

                                //PTK: ==> new code
                                $item=array('Years'=>$elements[0], 'Makes'=>array());
                                for($i=1;$i<count($elements);$i++)
                                {
                                    $make=trim($elements[$i]);
                                    //if($make=='')continue;  //PTK: if you want to remove empty lines uncoment this line, but in this case your array may will have rows with different     lengthes
                                    $item['Makes'][]=$make;
                                }
                                //PTK: <== new code
                                /* 
                                //PTK ==> original code
                                $item = array();  
                                foreach( $this->fields as $id => $field ) {  
                                        if( isset($elements[$id]) ) {  
                                                $item[$field] = $elements[$id];  
                                        }  
                                } 
                                //PTK <== original code
                                */ 
                                $content[] = $item;  
                        }  
                }  
        }  
        return $content;  
}
```

Comment: Hi Pati. I have edited my question with CSVReader library file I am using. Can you please show me where can I use your function CSV_parse? Which data I have to pass as a CSV file content?

Comment: Hi Viren, I have added new code. See after EDIT word

Comment: Hi Pati. Your new edited code works perfectly as per my desired output result. Thank you very for your help. Right now I don't have 15 reputations for upvote your answer. But when I will have 15 reputations, I will surely upvote your answer. God bless you.